# Unable to upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: do-release-upgrade

First on terminal:

sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade

and in the response

```
Fetched 828 kB in 3s (323 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I try:
apt list --upgradable

and

```
fwupd-signed/groovy-updates 1.30.2+1.4.7-0~20.10.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.27.1ubuntu3+1.5.11-0ubuntu1~20.04.1]
N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

I Try:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-proposed InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
```

Tried upgrading using
do-release-upgrade

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Comment: Tried apt-mark showhold. It is not returning any value    root@HHKL015:/home/anendukumarpoddar# apt-mark showhold
root@HHKL015:/home/anendukumarpoddar#

Comment: I suspect the upgradable package is in `groovy-proposed`. Please disable that repository and retry `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`. (While you're editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` I suggest also getting rid of the duplicate line 7 that apt warns about.)

Comment: Software & Updates -> Developer Options -> Unchecked Pre-released updates.